# What is the meaning of "over"?

Tags: meaning

In a book I've met the sentence and I can't understand the sense of the preposition "over". Would you so kind to explain this occasion of the usage of the preposition?

The context:
She noticed the movement of his eyes. Her own eyes widened, she mouthed down at him, "*Jess*"? He smiled **over** his gritted teeth and nodded.

[image]

Comment: It's a subtle blend of the literal and the metaphorical. There's a reference to A overcoming B ('You could hear the radio announcement even over the roaring of the crowd') but also the physical masking of the gritted teeth by the smiling face. He smiled, but it was a real effort. The expression 'grin and bear it' comes to mind.

Comment: Try going through the dictionary entries and applying each one to this context.  In many cases you’ll find that only one of them makes any sense.  If you find that two or more make sense and you can’t decide which one is intended, update the question to add your interpreration of each.

Comment: That is not the cleverest of ways to put it.Indeed one's risible muscles are situated over one's teeth.Perhaps the writer is juxtaposing two conflicting facial expressions here to achieve a certain effect: "Gritted teeth" (could imply pain, anger, etc.) and "smiled... " (could imply forbearance, affectation, etc.)

Comment: Claudia Brugman wrote [a dissertation on the meaning of the English word _over_](https://books.google.com/books/about/Story_of_over.html?id=deB3nQEACAAJ). It's quite surprising. For instance, _The town is over that hill_ and _The drone is over that hill_ represent very different uses of _over_, specifying very different places. Yet we understand them automatically.

Comment: – John Lawler,  in "The town is over that hill" here "over" means "beyond" and in "The drone is over that hill" means "above". i guess, is it right?